# Eclipse BIRT input parameter in FROM clause

Tags: eclipse, dataset, report, birt

I'm using eclipse birt to make my reports.
My goal is to take input parameter, to chose different table used to my dataset. I know that i can use something like this:

`id = ?`

In my `WHERE` clause. But i would like to accomplish something like that:

`FROM CONCAT('tablexyz',?)`

So i can do my report for tables `tablexyz17`, `tablexyz18`, `tablexyz19`, etc. I have tried to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM CONCAT('tablexyz',year)
WHERE year = ?
```

But it gave me an error.
Any ideas how can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use bind variables for this. Bind variables are designed to supply values (for varchar, number, date or whatever expressions), but you are trying to change the table.

But you can use something like this:

Write your query in a way that works for one of the tables, e.g.

```
select * from tablexyz17
```

Then, in the dataset's beforeOpen event, change the query text like this (untested, but you get the idea):

```
// paramYear is the name of your dataset parameter
var tableName = 'tablexyz' + this.getInputParameterValue("paramYear");
this.query = this.query.replace('tablexyz17', tableName);
```

Comment: Although this solution didn't work. I did something like this in my `beforeOpen` script: `this.queryText=this.queryText.replace("tablexyz117","tablexyz1"+params["year"].value);` and it worked fine. Thank you for help.

Comment: My proposed solution was based on dataset parameters, whereas yours uses a report parameter. It is important to understand the difference (for other readers). My solution requires that the parameter is still used in the query (that is, there has to be a question mark or a :name for the bind variable). I reformulate the query like this then: WITH params as (SELECT :table_name AS tab_name FROM DUAL) SELECT ... FROM tablexyz17 ...   This way, a corresponding bind variable for the dataset parameter is contained in the query but it doesn't influence the result. (I used Oracle SQL syntax here.)